# Global variables Xcos

Tags: scilab, xcos

I am new to Xcos. Is there a way for a block to read or write to a variable that other blocks could also access? or if there is a work around to achieving the same. Thanks

Comment: Did you have any success with the solution I proposed ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to right-click in diagram window and select "Set Context" ? You should be able to define global variables there.